# Trait inheritance with <:

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I was used to inherit from a trait like this:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
```

But recently I discovered by accident that it is also possible with `<:` :

```
trait A
trait B <: A
```

Why? What is the motivation? (Don't want to hear its written down in the specs.) It is not possible when a class comes into play.

Comment: That looks like a historical syntax. I've never seen this anywhere. Probably worth deprecating in a future version.

Comment: Pretty funny to hear that it's *not* written down in the spec. Surely time to deprecate or put behind the -source flag.

Answer (score 5):

This syntax was for an experimental language feature called [*virtual traits*](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/export/20327/scala/branches/devel-base-2.8.0/SIP/virtual-traits/sip-0000X.xhtml). It is a leftover from that. I would avoid the syntax as it can be confusing to people who don’t know about it (including you, since you had to ask this question).

Comment: [Virtual traits](http://manuel.weiel.eu/research/virtual-traits-for-scala/)